# Name for topology generated by the standard open sets of reals and every point that isn't zero.

Tags: general-topology

I'm interested in topological spaces that are easy to construct. In particular, **I'd like to know what this one is called so I can look it up in [pi-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/)**, assuming of course that it's interesting enough to be included there.

Let $(\mathbb{R}, \tau^R)$ be the standard topology on the reals.

Let $\sigma$ be the topology generated by $\tau^R \cup \{ \{x\} : x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus 0 \}$.

$(\mathbb{R}, \sigma)$ is a topological space. It is almost the discrete topology, except that any open set containing zero must have a standardly open subset.

Some preliminary observations.

- All of the open sets containing $0$ are in fact clopen.
- All the sets that are open but not closed get arbitrarily *close* to $0$, intuitively.

Comment: I don't know a name, but given a topological space $X$, and a point $x\in X$, then the set of all neighborhoods of $x$ combined with $\emptyset$ is a topology on X.

Comment: I've encountered this example before but don't think it has a canonical name. Current criteria to be included in pi-Base: https://github.com/pi-base/data/wiki/Reviewing#requirements-for-a-new-space Importantly, does it fulfill an empty search?

Comment: it would appear in this list: [π-Base, Search for `Cardinality $=\mathfrak c$+~Discrete+Has an isolated point+$T_2$`](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Cardinality+%24%3D%5Cmathfrak+c%24%2B%7EDiscrete%2BHas+an+isolated+point%2Bhau)

Comment: Hmm. Is your space a copy of https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000133 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your space is (subtlely) already in $\pi$-Base, under the name [S133: Post office metric on the plane](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000133).

I'll prove something a bit more general. Let $X$ be a metric space containing a point $0$, and let the sets $A_0=X\setminus B_1(0)$ and $A_{n+1}=B_{1/2^n}(0)\setminus B_{1/2^{n+1}}(0)$. Note $X\setminus\{0\}=\bigcup\{A_n:n<\omega\}$ and suppose $|A_n|=|\mathbb R|$ for all $n<\omega$. Give $X$ the **post-office metric** $$
d(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if }x=y\\
d(x,0)+d(0,y)&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I claim that $X$ is homeomorphic to your space $\mathbb R$. Let $\theta:X\to\mathbb R$ be defined as follows. First, choose $\theta\upharpoonright A_0$ to be an arbitrary bijection from $A_0$ to $\mathbb R\setminus(-1,1)$. Then, choose $\theta\upharpoonright A_{n+1}$to be an arbitrary bijection from $A_{n+1}$ to $(-1/2^{n},1/2^n)\setminus(-1/2^{n+1},1/2^{n+1})$. Finally, let $\theta(0)=0$.

We have a bijection, so we now show it is a continuous open map.

To see that it is open, let $x\in X\setminus\{0\}$. Then $\{x\}$ is open, and $\theta[\{x\}]\subseteq\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is open. For $0\in X$, choose the basic open set $B_{1/2^n}(0)$. Then $\theta[B_{1/2^n}(0)]=(-1/2^n,1/2^n)$ is open.

To see that it is continuous, let $y\in \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$. Then $\{y\}$ is open, and $\theta^\leftarrow[\{y\}]\subseteq X\setminus\{0\}$ is open. For $0\in\mathbb R$, choose the basic open set $(-1/2^n,1/2^n)$. Then $\theta^\leftarrow[(-1/2^n,1/2^n)]=B_{1/2^n}(0)$ is open.

---

I'd very much appreciate it if you'd like to contribute this new perspective on S133 to the $\pi$-Base. [I'll create an issue and link it here.](https://github.com/pi-base/data/issues/504)