Are almost discrete metrizable spaces always completely metrizable?
Say an almost discrete space has exactly one non-isolated point. An example of this property is the so-called metric fan $\left\{\left(\dfrac{1}{m},\dfrac{1}{mn}\right):m,n\in\mathbb Z^+\right\}\cup\{(0,0)\}\subseteq\mathbb R^2$.
As a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ this space is metrizable (hence the name). Is this space completely metrizable? More generally, is any metrizable almost discrete space completely metrizable?

EDIT: (I suspect that the almost discrete metrizable spaces are exactly the metric fans with one or more "blades": the non-isolated point is the limit of several "blades" of discrete countable sets, with neighborhoods containing all but $N$-many points of every blade for some $N$.) Well, maybe not, as Ulli observed in their comment pointing out the sum of a convergent sequence and an uncountable discrete space.
EDIT again: So instead: let the generalized metric fan $\kappa\times\omega\cup\{\infty\}$ be defined for any cardinal $\kappa$, with points of $\kappa\times\omega$ isolated, and neighborhoods of $\infty$ containing $\kappa\times(\omega\setminus N)$ for some $N<\omega$. Is every metrizable almost-discrete space the union of a generalized metric fan and a discrete space?
I think this is a red herring: consider the disjoint union of discrete spaces $X_n$ of increasing size $\kappa_n$ with neighborhoods of $\infty$ containing all by finitely-many $X_n$. Leaving the thoughts up for posterity only.

Let $x_0$ be the only nonisolated point. We play the strong Choquet game on $X$. If at any point player I plays $U_i$ and $x_i\in U_i$ isolated, then player II answers with $V_i={x_i}$ which forces the game to be constant from the next step until the end, so that II wins. If player I never plays an isolated $x_i$, then he must always play some nbhd $U_i$ of $x$ and II answers with $V_i$ contained in $U_i$ and containing $x$. At the end of the game $\bigcap U_i$ will contain $x$, so II wins also in this case, hence $X$ is completely metrizable

Nice. This comment should be an answer I think.

I don't quite remember the hypothesis of the equivalence between strong Choquet and completely metrizable. It surely works for separable metric spaces (hence for the metric fan), but does it work in general?

Metrizable spaces are completely metrizable if and only if they are strong Choquet. But I don't have either text on hand to confirm.

Not sure, whether I understood the definition of blades or your assumption about the characterization of almost discrete, metrizable spaces correctly. But does it include spaces like $(\omega+1) \oplus D$
(topological sum of a convergent sequence and a discrete space)?
Of course, these spaces are almost discrete and metrizable, but not separable in general.

Oh, good catch Ulli. If $D$ is uncountable that would not fit in my originally pitched characterization.

Yes, separability is not needed, see also here for example. I'll write an answer

The strong Choquet game argument generalizes (easily) to metric spaces with finitely many nonisolated points, and I think that with a little more work it could generalize to metric spaces with finite Cantor-Bendixson rank although I didn't check carefully

I once convinced myself that a scattered, hereditarily paracompact, regular, T2 space of pointwise countable type is Cech complete. But this was quite a tedious proof!

Here is a reference for "scattered metrizable spaces are completely metrizable" (Corollary 2.2).

@Ulli is scattered the same as having countable Cantor-Bendixson rank for metric spaces?

@Alessandro Codenotti: I guess it's an interesting question, whether "$\Rightarrow$" is correct. It seems to be, but, to be honest, I don't know. Sorry, about "$\Leftarrow$", I'm just a little bit confused  (maybe, it's too late now): isn't the Cantor–Bendixson rank of $\mathbb Q = 0$, hence finite and countable? Of course, $\mathbb Q$ is not scattered.

@Ulli $\mathbb Q$ has no isolated points, so it is its own Cantor-Bendixson derivative

@Alessandro Codenotti: yes, exactly. But this means
$\mathbb Q = \mathbb Q^0 = \mathbb Q^1$, hence Cantor–Bendixson rank of
$\mathbb Q = 0$,
for instance, according to Wikipedia's defintion. Or what's your definition of Cantor–Bendixson rank? Or what's your value of Cantor–Bendixson rank of  $\mathbb Q$?

Oh, I see, sorry about that. With Cantor-Bendixson rank of $X$ I meant the least $\alpha$ such that $(X)^{\alpha+1}$ is empty (or $\infty$ if there is no such $\alpha$, as is the case for $\mathbb Q$). But yes it seems that this is not how the term is used in topology (but I do think this is the definition of Cantor-Bendixson rank model theorists have in mind when they say that the Morley rank agrees with the Cantor-Bendixson rank in the space of types)

Ah, I think now, we got it: $X^\alpha = \emptyset$ for some $\alpha$ is (almost trivially) equivalent to scattered. So your initial question "is scattered the same as having countable Cantor-Bendixson rank for metric spaces?" is trivially true for "$\Leftarrow$", since you define Cantor-Bendixson rank $ = \infty$, hence uncountable, for non-scattered spaces. Correct?

@Ulli Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Any almost discrete space is strong Choquet, and a strong choquet metrizable space is completely metrizable.
To see that almost discrete spaces are strong Choquet let $X$ be almost discrete and let $x\in X$ be the only non-isolated point. If during a run of the strong Choquet game Player I ever plays $U_i$ and $x_i\in U_i$ isolated, then Player II answers with $V_i=\{x_i\}$. This forces $U_n=V_n=\{x_i\}$ and $x_n=x_i$ for any $n\geq i$, so that at the end of the game $\bigcap U_j=\{x_i\}$ is nonempty and Player II wins. If instead Player I plays $x_i=x$ for every $i$, then regardless of how player II answers (for example with $V_i=U_i$ for all $i$), at the end of the play we will have that $x\in\bigcap U_i$, so that Player II wins again. In other words player II has a winning strategy in the strong Choquet game, so that $X$ is a strong Choquet space, as claimed.

In fact, almost discrete $T_1$ and first-countable spaces are always completely metrizable.
Let $\{U_n:n<\omega\}$ be a decreasing countable base at the non-isolated point $\infty$, with $U_0$ being the entire space; for $x\not=\infty$, choose $n_x<\omega$ maximal with $x\in U_{n_x}$. Then we set $d(x,\infty)=\frac{1}{n_x+1}$, and $d(x,y)=\frac{1}{n_x+1}+\frac{1}{n_y+1}$. This satisfies the requirements for a metric, and it does induce the topology: for $x\not=\infty$, $B\left(x,\frac{1}{n_x+2}\right)=\{x\}$, and we have also $B\left(\infty,\frac{1}{n+0.5}\right)=U_n$.
Alessandro gave a nice game-theoretic proof showing now there must be a complete metric, but we can in fact directly show this metric itself is complete. Take a Cauchy sequence $x_n$, and suppose it does not converge to $\infty$. Choose $M<\omega$ such that a subsequence of $x_n$ is outside $U_M$. Let $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{M+2}$ and by Cauchy take $N<\omega$ such that $d(x_n,x_{n'})<\frac{1}{M+2}$ for $n,n'\geq N$. Choose $p\geq \max\{M,N\}$ such that $x_p$ is outside $U_M$. Then $n_{x_p}<M$, and $$B\left(x_p,\frac{1}{M+2}\right)\subseteq B\left(x_p,\frac{1}{n_{x_p}+2}\right)=\{x_p\}.$$ It follows for all $n\geq p$ that $d(x_p,x_n)<\frac{1}{M+2}$ and therefore $x_n=x_p$, showing $x_n$ converges trivially.

Almost discrete spaces need not be $T_1$ (e.g., excluded point topology). But I think it would make perfect sense, to add $T_1$ to the definition. Then they would fulfill the nicest separation axioms ($T_2$, Tychonoff, hereditarily ultraparacompactness).

Thanks for pointing out my oversight: I was assuming $T_1$ when I said "choose $n_x<\omega$ maximal with $x\in U_{n_x}$".

Nice construction.  Similar to the "post office metric" from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4833751.

Wouldn't a simple argument show that your metric is complete?  So would give a direct simple proof that such spaces are completely metrizable.

I took your suggestion PatrickR.
